# opening a directory with single quote in its name

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, filesystems

I have to open a directory from terminal but the directory name contains a single quote, how Can I open it? Here is the name of the directory

```
02. Setting Up 'Shop
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what OS you're using.

Comment: remotely accessing CentOS from Mac terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either escape spaces and the quote with `\`, or wrap the whole directory name in double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

suround the directory name with quotes

```
$ cd "02. Setting Up 'Shop"
```

or mask the 'special' characters

```
$ cd 02.\ Settings\ Up\ \'Shop
```

Comment: -bash: 33m]ommand not found
-bash: 31m: command not found

Comment: a dot doesn't have to be escaped.

Comment: @coure2011: what exactly did you enter to get that error message back? Quoted string or using escape sequences ('\')? And you don't enter the '$' in the beginning. These commands are used to color the terminal output ([0;33m -> yellow, 0;31m -> red). You can try to set a minimalistic prompt, eg. export PS1='\h:\W \u\$'. Or to check your prompt: echo "$PS1"

Comment: @danielkullmann: Of course you're right, sill me :)